# How can I JSON path without a values?

Tags: json, jsonpath

So, I'm wondering how I can JSON path to the id `508018304019857419`, I'm trying out `$[?(@ == 508018304019857419)].rolesList` but it just doesn't work. What can I do?

I'm trying to find `508018304019857419` and collect `rolesList`

*JSON:*

```
[
   {
      "508018304019857419":{
         "rolesList":[
            "Guest",
            "Presidential Team",
            "Chief Executive Officer",
            "[-] Co Founder",
            "[-] Founder",
            "[-] Group Holder"
         ]
      }
   },
   {
      "222078108977594368":{
         "rolesList":[
            "Guest",
            "Test1",
            "Test2",
            "Test3",
            "Test4",
            "Owner"
         ]
      }
   }
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$.[508018304019857419].rolesList` should do.

`$.` is all children of the root, `[508018304019857419]` is the "508018304019857419" key of each of them (the ones that don't have such a key are filtered out), and then `.rolesList` drills down.